# Which formats are supported by operator>> for boost::chrono::duration?

Tags: c++, boost, c++-chrono

Can anybody tell me which formats are supported when reading in a `boost::chrono::duration` from a stream? I do not find any documentation about this.
I read the header and got some information from there - but I do not completely understand it.

A very small test program:

```
#define BOOST_CHRONO_VERSION 2
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>

using namespace boost::chrono;

int main() {
  boost::chrono::seconds tp1;
  std::cin >> tp1;
  std::cout << symbol_format << tp1 << std::endl;
}
```

When feeding in some of the units I found in the appropriate header, it works well:

```
$ echo "4 seconds" | ./a.out 
4 s
$ echo "6 minutes" | ./a.out 
360 s
$ echo "2 h" | ./a.out 
7200 s
```

What I want to do, is some combined approach - which does not work:

```
1 minute 30 seconds
1:30 minutes
1.5 minutes
2 h 6 min 24 seconds
```

For me it looks that the parsing stops directly after the first unit. I tried some different delimiters (like ':', ',', ...) without success.

Two questions:

1. Is this combined / extended kind of passing in `boost::chrono::duration` possible? If so, how?
2. If I understand the boost header correctly, a minute can be expressed like 'min' or 'minute', a second can be expressed like 's' or 'second' - but not 'sec'.  Can anybody point me to some documentation of the supported abbreviations? (Looks that this is not that straight forward.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the list of duration units, please check the docs [duration_units.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.io.duration_units_hpp) or view the [code](https://github.com/boostorg/chrono/blob/develop/include/boost/chrono/io/duration_units.hpp#L524)

```
"s" / "second" / "seconds" 
"min" / "minute" / "minutes"
"h" / "hour" / > "hours"
```

If you need to parse several duration entries, you could write a function  like `parse_time`:

```
#define BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY
#define BOOST_CHRONO_VERSION 2

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::chrono;

seconds parse_time(const string& str) {
  auto first = make_split_iterator(str, token_finder(algorithm::is_any_of(",")));
  auto last = algorithm::split_iterator<string::const_iterator>{};

  return accumulate(first, last, seconds{0}, [](const seconds& acc, const iterator_range<string::const_iterator>& r) {
    stringstream ss(string(r.begin(), r.end()));
    seconds d;
    ss >> d;
    if(!ss) {
      throw std::runtime_error("invalid duration");
    }
    return acc + d;
  });
}

int main() {
  string str1 = "5 minutes, 15 seconds";
  cout << parse_time(str1) << endl; // 315 seconds

  string str2 = "1 h, 5 min, 30 s";
  cout << parse_time(str2) << endl; // 3930 seconds

  try {
    string str3 = "5 m";
    cout << parse_time(str3) << endl; // throws
  } catch(const runtime_error& ex) {
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

`parse_time` splits on a delimiter `,` and processes separate durations. In case of an error it throws the `runtime_error`.

[Run it online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ef6c642f9d96db8)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Changes a couple of things for my implementation, like using a template. Also decided to use space as a separator: e.g. '2h 30min' is a valid duration specification.